# R tidyverse: fct_relevel "unknown levels"

Tags: r, forcats

I'm trying to use `forcats::fct_relevel` to specify the levels in a column, the way I've used it in `ggplot`, but it's giving an error about "unknown levels".

Here is a chart of the cheeses I have eaten per month:

```
cheeses<-tribble(
  ~mymonth, ~Brie, ~Stilton,
  1, 4, 2, 
  2, 4, 1,
  3, 1, 3,
  4, 1, 5,
  5, 2, 4,
  6, 3, 1
)
```

and a list of the months:

```
cheesemonth<-c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun")
```

According to pages like [this one](https://cmdlinetips.com/2021/02/tidyverse-tips-case-when-fct_relvel/), I should be able to do the following:

```
cheeses %>% 
  mutate(mymonth=factor(mymonth)) %>% 
  mutate(mymonth=fct_relevel(mymonth, cheesemonth))
```

and have the items in `mymonth` replaced by the items in `cheesemonth`.  But instead I get:

```
6 unknown levels in `f`: Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, and Jun
```

and I'm at a loss to understand why.

If I replace the last line with:

```
mutate(mymonth=case_match(mymonth, "1" ~ "Jan", "2" ~ "Feb", "3" ~ "Mar", "4" ~ "Apr", "5" ~ "May", "6" ~ "Jun"))
```

then it's fine, but this is more typing, and means I can't re-use the `cheesemonth` list.

So why do I get the `unknown levels` error?

Comment: Why not simply use `cheeses %>% mutate(mymonth = factor(mymonth, labels = cheesemonth))`? It doesn't sound like you really need the forcats package here.

Comment: I re-opened this since  the nature of those questions is that `factor` is a good answer but here `ordered` would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fct_relevel` reorders levels.  To change the labels, which forcats calls values, use `lvls_revalue`

```
library(forcats)

lvls_revalue(as.character(cheeses$mymonth), cheesemonth)
$$ [1] Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun
## Levels: Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun
```

or use `fct`

```
library(forcats)

fct(cheesemonth[cheeses$mymonth], cheesemonth)
## [1] Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun
## Levels: Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun
```

It is even easier with base R:

```
factor(cheeses$mymonth, labels = cheesemonth)
## [1] Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun
## Levels: Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun
```

or given that months have a natural order you may wish to create an ordered factor (also base R):

```
ordered(cheeses$mymonth, labels = cheesemonth)
## [1] Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun
## Levels: Jan < Feb < Mar < Apr < May < Jun
```

Note that R has a built-in `month.abb` vector (English only) so we could eliminate `cheesemonth` and write:

```
month.abb
## [1] "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" "May" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Oct" "Nov" "Dec"

ordered(cheeses$mymonth, labels = month.abb[1:6])
## [1] Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun
## Levels: Jan < Feb < Mar < Apr < May < Jun
```

or to allow for months that are not present in the data

```
ordered(cheeses$mymonth, levels = 1:12, labels = month.abb)
## [1] Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun
## 12 Levels: Jan < Feb < Mar < Apr < May < Jun < Jul < Aug < Sep < ... < Dec
```

Comment: A BIG thank-you to jay.sf and you, Gabor - I've spent another couple of hours typing stuff, and I think I finally understand what I was doing wrong.  Thanks too for the info on ordered() and the month.abb list, which will be really useful. So kind of you both to share your time.

Answer (score 0):

You have levels `1:6` and the six labels in `cheesemonth` which can be combined in `factor` like so:

```
cheeses$mymonth <- factor(cheeses$mymonth, levels=1:6, labels=cheesemonth)
cheeses
#   mymonth Brie Stilton
# 1     Jan    4       2
# 2     Feb    4       1
# 3     Mar    1       3
# 4     Apr    1       5
# 5     May    2       4
# 6     Jun    3       1
```

This also works with pipes in base R,

```
cheeses |> transform(mymonth=factor(mymonth, levels=1:6, labels=cheesemonth))
```

or using `dplyr`.

```
library(magrittr)
cheeses %>% dplyr::mutate(mymonth=factor(mymonth, levels=1:6, labels=cheesemonth))
```

---

*Data:*

```
cheeses <- structure(list(mymonth = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Brie = c(4, 4, 
1, 1, 2, 3), Stilton = c(2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference, here´s a late but very simple solution with `lubridate::month()`.

```
library(lubridate)

cheeses <- mutate(cheeses, mymonth = month(mymonth, label = TRUE, abbr = TRUE))

# A tibble: 6 × 3
  mymonth  Brie Stilton
  <ord>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 jan         4       2
2 fev         4       1
3 mar         1       3
4 abr         1       5
5 mai         2       4
6 jun         3       1

# ---------------------

str(cheeses)

tibble [6 × 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ mymonth: Ord.factor w/ 12 levels "jan"<"fev"<"mar"<..: 1 2 3 4 5 6
 $ Brie   : num [1:6] 4 4 1 1 2 3
 $ Stilton: num [1:6] 2 1 3 5 4 1
```